Separate Highlights, Midtones, Shadows
I have this placeholder image (the bear cubs). I'm trying to capture the highlights, midtones and shadows produced as separate image files with alpha channels. The placeholder image -- instead, it is simply blank area of alpha data.

I understand I can use render passes to separate these into layers, but I don't know how to export them as images. Sorry if this questions been asked before. Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.
